# made changes, compiled and regret

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, restore, undo, compiled

I made today few changes by ctrl+h to all the solution.
 When I understood my mistakes I tried to undo it with ctrl-Z but the results were awful.

The question is : How can I reload the last compiled project before I had done this stupid move.
Lets say I want the solution as it was at yesterday.

Thanks for your help,
Eliran.

Comment: In the old times, we used backups. Nowadays we use version control systems such as git or mercurial. If you did not implement one, I really do not know how to reverse the situation. I really advise to use  Git.

Comment: Not a solution but maybe you should use [Version control](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)

Comment: Have you tried using `Control+H` to reverse your problem?

Comment: It's harsh lesson this one, now you are going to become as fervent about source control and backups as the rest of us aren't you.

Comment: If you're lucky and have [File History/Shadow Copies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) turned on, you can restore the previous snapshot of your file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Once saved, the changes are irreversible. That's the point of backups. There are tools to decompile your .NET executable, but as not all sourcecode is actually compiled into the executable (for example formatting and comments are not), you will never get your original code back.

You may want to look into source control software like `Git`, `Subversion` or `Team Foundation Server` to handle this problem properly next time.

Comment: Not my downvote, but Visual Studio saves every time you build.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I was about to say that.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I feel old. You are right, "newer" (I think 2001 onwards) versions auto-save :) I expanded my post a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try decompiling the old binary with tools like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). But in general that is the reason why you use a source control system.